# How a struct being typedef-ed to multiple names?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I've recently started to study about structs and pointers but there is something I didn't fully understand about the design of a `struct`. I understand the declaration of the `struct` i.e `typedef struct Alias` and its content but I don't understand `Get_noAllyp` and `*no_getOf` at the end of the statement. What are they? I couldn't really find a good source either.

```
typedef struct  Alias {
    char    *s_a_name;
    char    **s_aliases;
    short   *s_dumr;
    int     s_get_sum;
}Get_noAllyp, *no_getOf; /*Here, I don't understand this one. 
                        Where did these two variables come from?
                        And one of them is a pointer.*/
```

Comment: Don't use both `C` and `C++` tags. They are different languages and they have different rules (although they have a lot in common).

Comment: The posted code is creating two types (Get_noAllyp and *no_getOf)  However, the struct tag name is 'Alias'  so those two types have names that are very mis-leading.  The misleading type names will result in misunderstandings, code bugs, etc.  In general, never typedef a struct definition.  It is much clearer to write 'struct Alias' or 'struct Alias*' than to try to remember that 'no_getOf' is actually a pointer and is actually a pointer to a struct Alias.  Typedef'ing a struct clutters the code, leads to mis-understandings, and clutters the compiler name space.

Comment: @user3629249 Well thank you sir! But the snippet code was just a pure example of how some structs can be seen in source codes thus very annoying if the struct has some crappy name at its end like given above. I do understand that such struct names is not a good practice and very confusing. But yet again, I would still need a clarification even though it was _Alias and *pAlias :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It defines multiple `typedef`s, i.e multilple "names" for the same thing, while the second is a pointer to it.

The first one `Get_noAllyp` is the name given for the struct, while `no_getOf` represents a pointer to it.

I.e, writing `no_getOf` is completely the same as writing `Get_noAllyp *` in function signatures or variable declarations.

Comment: Oh.. Awesome, I really needed to understand this one because I could not simply understand a simple thing when such structs came along. Thanks Mark

Answer (score 14):

Here, there are two `typedef`s being crated in a short-hand manner. The above `typedef` can be broken down like

```
typedef struct  Alias {
    char    *s_a_name;
    char    **s_aliases;
    short   *s_dumr;
    int     s_get_sum;
}Get_noAllyp;                  

typedef struct  Alias * no_getOf;
```

So,

- `Get_noAllyp` represents `struct  Alias`
- `no_getOf` represents `struct  Alias *`

Comment: Oh awesome.. Pointer one is representing pointer of the struct? Awesome and thanks Sourav!

Answer (score 13):

The code:

```
struct Alias {
    char    *s_a_name;
    char    **s_aliases;
    short   *s_dumr;
    int     s_get_sum;
}
```

defines a new data type that has the name `Alias` and is a `struct`. The original design of the `C` language is a bit clumsy here as it requires the struct type names to be always prefixed with the `struct` keyword when they are used.

This means the code:

```
struct  Alias {
    char    *s_a_name;
    char    **s_aliases;
    short   *s_dumr;
    int     s_get_sum;
} Get_noAllyp, *no_getOf;
```

declares the variable `Get_noAllyp` of type `struct Alias` and the variable `no_getOf` of type `pointer to struct Alias`.

By placing the `typedef` keyword in front, the identifiers `Get_noAllyp` and `no_getOf` become types (and not variables).

`Get_noAllyp` is the same as `struct Alias` and `no_getOf` is the same as `struct Alias *` (i.e. a pointer to a struct Alias`).

Now you can write:

```
struct Alias x;
struct Alias *y;
```

or

```
Get_noAllyp x;
no_getOf y;
```

to declare `x` as a variable of type `struct Alias` and `y` as a variable of type `pointer to a struct Alias`.

Comment: Awesome explanation @axiac! Thanks :) I can finally read codes thus write in a better way!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `typedef` in the second example?