# typedef struct with second specifier after the name

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

I understand that while declaring a `typedef struct` you give it a name after the curly bracket. S_STORE in this case.

But what does ***LPSTORE** mean in the following example?

```
typedef struct MySTORE
    {
      WCHAR Name;
      ...
    } S_STORE, *LPSTORE;
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370036/how-a-struct-being-typedef-ed-to-multiple-names)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How a struct being typedef-ed to multiple names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370036/how-a-struct-being-typedef-ed-to-multiple-names)

Answer (score 2):

This creates two typedef-aliases in a single line.

It's equivalent to

```
struct MySTORE { WCHAR Name; ... };
typedef MySTORE S_STORE;
typedef MySTORE *LPSTORE;
```

The typedefs can also be written as:

```
using S_STORE = MySTORE;
using LPSTORE = MySTORE *;
```